# Network-wide feature request to support TeX in tables

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stackexchange, mathjax

Many of us here frequently use MathJax, whether for this site or another site on the SE Network.

Recently SE added support for tables but ignored the needs of the TeX community, who wish to be able to type TeX symbols/formulas/etc. as well.

#### [This is the feature request on Meta.SE, to support MathJax in tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357525/391772).

Here are some examples from Matter Modelling community where such support would be needed:

- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1720/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1247/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3857/5
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/361/5

Feel free to support the feature request on the main Meta, submit examples of posts from the Computational Science community in answers to this post, and leave any other feedback.